# Notepad++ Column Editor

Tags: notepad++, multiple-columns

In Notepad++ I have been using Edit->Column Editor to put a number on each line of a text file, it's great!

Is there a way you can do this for all opened documents, to save me doing this for each text file?

Comment: The quickest way is to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write a Python script to do this. Perform these steps (omit if N/A):

- Install [PythonScript](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/Python%20Script%201.0.8.0)
- Go to *Plugins* -> *Python Script* -> *New Script*
- Create a new `AddLineIdsAllTabs.py` script
- Add these contents:

---

```
offset = 1 # Define the offset (step) value
fileNames = notepad.getFiles()              # get all open files
for x in fileNames[1:]:                     # iterate thru all tabs (first is doubled, thus skipping)
    filename, bufferID, index, view = x     # get the details
    notepad.activateIndex(view, index)      # activate the tab
    line_number = editor.getLineCount()     # get line count
    for id in range(line_number):           # iterate thru all lines
        editor.gotoLine(id)                 # go to line with a given ID
        editor.home()                       # place cursor at the line start
        editor.addText("{0}. ".format(str(id+offset))) # Add text
```

---

Now, run the script from *Plugins* -> *Python Script* -> *Scripts* -> *AddLineIdsAllTabs*.

**Alternative script**

After the `notepad.activateIndex(view, index)` line, use

```
editor.selectAll()
notepad.runMenuCommand('TextFX Tools', 'Insert Line Numbers')
```